# WCF best practice for client/server with notifications

Tags: wcf, architecture, client-server, wcf-client

First off: We have got a working solution for the problem I'm about to describe but it just doesn't feel right.

We have an application with one application server and about 30 - 100 clients. Scaling the server is not an issue. Most important  are the **notifications from the server to the clients**, but of course there are also service-methods to be called from the client to the server.

What we do now is that we created a service contract with a callback channel, register the client in the service (i.e. the service contains a list of active callback channels) and send notifications via those callback channels.

Problems we needed to navigate around were:

1. **Timeouts of the connection** - the service now contains some KeepAlive method that is pinged by the clients about every minute
2. **Re-connecting the client after server or network failure** - which is the main point I'm concerned about. At the moment we have a long-running client object (service reference, inherited from `DuplexClientBase`) to call the service and the callback object to handle received notifications. On `client.Faulted` we try to replace the client and the callback object with a newly created client until the server can be reached again. This approach involves quite some weird exception handling...

**Question:** Would it be better to start a WCF service on each client and register the endpoint of each client on the server? Is there any better solution for the two problems described?

Edit: The point is: Am I missing something? - I believe the described architecture should be quite common and I am looking for the "default", best way to do it. Is there not some sample out there for this sort of setup?

Answer (score 3):

If your issues are around availability (in this case the availability of both service -> consumer and consumer -> service) then maybe you should consider using some more fault tolerant transport like MSMQ (perhaps using netMsmqBinding).

You could replace the complex WCF callback infrastructure with a simple, durable subscription store.

When you need to send a "callback" simply retrieve the list of consumers from your subscription store and send a message to each.

Connections would never time out because you wouldn't have a stateful connection.

Re-connections from consumers to service after network failures also is solved - in-fact small network outages would not even be noticeable.

Apologies this does not directly answer your original question, and appreciate re-work on this scale may not be within the scope of your requirement.